# Python substring matching domain exclude subdomains

Tags: python, subdomain, match

I have a list of hosts that are part of multiple domains and subdomains. I'm trying to convert the list to a dict:list so the hosts are organized by domain/subdomain.

Pythons 'in' string matching would match all subdomains and domain. I was trying /(?!sub).domain/ as my regex but that doesn't seem to be matching correctly.

Trying to translate List1 to Dict based on List2

```
# A list of every host
host_list = [
  'host1.domain.com',
  'host2.domain.com',
  'host20.sub.domain.com',
  'host31.sub.domain.com',
  'host1.example.com',
  'host1.sub.example.com'
]

# A list of all domains we want to organize in the dictionary
domain_list = [
  'two.sub.domain',
  'sub.example',
  'sub.domain',
  'domain',
  'example'
]
```

Desired results

```
domain_dict = {
  'domain': ['host1.domain.com', 'host2.domain.com'],
  'sub.domain': ['host20.sub.domain.com', 'host31.sub.domain.com'],
  'example': ['host1.sub.example.com'],
  'sub.example': ['host1.sub.example.com']
}
```

**Solution where we still have one list of domains and support multiple subdomains.**

One caveat about this is the list of domains need to start from the deepest (most specific) subdomain. See the domain_list order has *sub.domain* before *domain*.

```
# We want to protect the original host list
host_list_copy = list(host_list)

for domain in domain_list:
    # Get only the hosts that are part of the same subdomain/domain
    temp_host_list = [x for x in host_list_copy if (domain in x)]
    # Add the list to the dictionary
    domain_dict[domain] = temp_host_list
    # Remove the temp_host_list records from the original host_list_copy 
    host_list_copy[:] = [x for x in host_list_copy if x not in temp_host_list]
```

Comment: Are you tying to construct the dictionary with the two lists?

Comment: Please focus on *what* are you trying to achieve (what is the goal of all this) it's more important than *how* you're trying to do it.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi List 2 is a list of all domains/subdomains and is used for checking the strings in List1. List 2 also is the key for the dictionary, so any match will be appended to a list with that domain in list2 as the key. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @alfasin I'm trying to organize a list of hosts by their domains.

Comment: Make a list of domains and corresponding subdomains, don't put them together.

Comment: So the `dict` is part of the solution - not of the problem, right? If I understand correctly, the problem is: you have two lists, one with domains and subdomains and the other is a list of hosts. You want to check each host if it "fits" to one of the domains/subdomains from the previous list. Each such "fitting" should be recorded somewhere. Is that a correct description?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi That is true I could separate it but that would mean I'd have to create a list for each level of subdomains if say there's host1.sub2.sub1.domain.com I don't see that happening in the future but I'd like to make it more roubust if I could.

Comment: I should say I have control over List2 as I created that but list 1 is given from an API call.

Comment: So you don't need regex here, just look if `'domain' in host` and if it is, see if `'sub.domain' in host` as well. String comparison is less expansive than regex.

Comment: LF4 how does my solution work for you. The subdomains should correspond with the domains in order.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditionals:

```
list1 = [
  'host1.domain.com',
  'host2.domain.com',
  'host20.sub.domain.com',
  'host31.sub.domain.com',
  'host1.example.com',
  'host1.sub.example.com'
]

list2 = [
    'domain',
    'example'
]

list3 = [
  'sub.domain',
  'sub.example'
]

my_dict = {i:[] for i in list2 + list3}

for i in list1:
    for j in zip(list2, list3):
        if j[1] in i:
            my_dict[j[1]].append(i)

        elif j[0] in i:
            my_dict[j[0]].append(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it (after a billion edits):

```
hosts = [
  'host1.domain.com',
  'host2.domain.com',
  'host20.sub.domain.com',
  'host31.sub.domain.com',
  'host1.example.com',
  'host1.sub.example.com'
]

domains = [
  'domain',
  'sub.domain',
  'example',
  'sub.example'
]

import re
import pprint

dot = r'.'
anything_but_dot = r'[^.]*'
prefix = anything_but_dot + dot

answer = {}
for domain in domains:
    compiled = re.compile(prefix + domain)
    answer[domain] = []
    for host in hosts:
        if compiled.match(host):
            answer[domain].append(host)

pprint.pprint(answer)
```

this gets the result:

```
{'domain': ['host1.domain.com', 'host2.domain.com'],
 'example': ['host1.example.com'],
 'sub.domain': ['host20.sub.domain.com', 'host31.sub.domain.com'],
 'sub.example': ['host1.sub.example.com']}
```